# Why are my analoge sticks not working properly?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

I have 3 Xbox One controllers, one of which works fine. However, the other two have an issue with the analogue sticks. For some reason, when they aren't being touched at all they act like they're being pushed up. This makes it incredibly hard to play first person shooter games in particular, as the aim is always moving up.

Why is this happening, and is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the analog stick on that controller has gone out of alignment. I've had this problem as well. In my experience, the only thing that fixed it was to buy a new controller. However, [Microsoft has a series of troubleshooting steps you can try first](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_support/xbox_one_support/f/4677/t/1846667.aspx), summarized here:

1. Make sure that your controller has fresh batteries and that your
   controller is updated.
2. Press and hold the power button on your Xbox One console for 10 seconds.
3. Once your console is powered off, unplug the power cord.
4. Wait 5 minutes and then plug in your console.
5. Power on your console and try resyncing the controller to your console again.

They also mention you can request a replacement through their online service center, [found here](https://myservice.xbox.com/en-US/Pages/Welcome.aspx). I don't have any experience with that.

As noted by Timelord64:

> I've dealt with Microsoft directly for this, before. It is important to note that their procedure is to replace the controller, if possible. Unfortunately, this also means they will send back a standard controller on occasion, even if you send away a special edition or even an elite controller. Should they replace an elite controller with another elite controller, they are known for not including the accessories, so it is advised to send it off without the extra buttons or paddles.

The takeaway being: you'll probably get another controller, not necessarily the same model. Send only the essentials in.

Comment: I've dealt with Microsoft directly for this, before. It is important to note that their procedure is to replace the controller, if possible. Unfortunately, this also means they will send back a standard controller on occasion, even if you send away a special edition or even an elite controller. Should they replace an elite controller with another elite controller, they are known for not including the accessories, so it is advised to send it off without the extra buttons or paddles.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, added it into the answer for posterity.